# Calculating sum

Tags: infinite-loop

```
 mm1 = {1 , 2}; mm2 = {3, 5};
 xxm = mm1*x + mm2*y ;
 mm6 = 0;
 m7m = Do[mm6 = mm6 + Replace[xxm, {mm1 -> mm1[[i]], mm2 -> mm2[[i]]}, {i, Length[mm1]}];
 mm6
```

This is giving me wrong result. As per the knowledge, it should give 3x+8y. It might be due to the 'Replace' command. However, I am not able to understand how to write the code in such a way that xxm will be outside of the body of 'Do' function and mm1 and mm2 will be changed inside the body of 'Do' function as per 'i' changes.

Comment: FWIW, `Plus @@ xxm` gives the desired result.

Comment: The most obvious issue with your code is that you are assigning values to `mm1` and `mm2` and then trying to use them symbolically. Why not use different symbols in the definition of `xxm`?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very ugly, non-*Mathematica* representation of your coefficients.  Here's an answer to your question, but I strongly recommend you study the basics of the *Mathematica* to get the foundations before you spend too much time trying to force this powerful, elegant language to function as a different language.

```
mm1 = {1, 2};
mm2 = {3, 5};
Total[mm1] x + Total[mm2] y
```

Another approach, which likely seems too foreign to beginners, is:

```
Total@(Total[#[[1]]] #[[2]] & /@ {{mm1, x}, {mm2, y}})
```

Or

```
Total@Transpose[{mm1, mm2}].{x, y}
```

Or

```
Plus @@ Transpose[{mm1, mm2}].{x, y}
```